# Alter table add primary key not recognised MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, alter

I am trying to run the statement `ALTER TABLE invoice_partitioned DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(invoice_partitioned.id, invoice_partitioned.department_code);`

This produces a syntax error (Error Code 1064) when run. MySQL Workbench is highlighting the bracket after ADD PRIMARY KEY, with the message '"(" is not valid at this position for this server version'.

Is there any way to resolve this issue? I am on MySQL Community Server 8.0.19

Comment: Why don't you make two statements. Do drop primary key first and then make other statement for add primary key would surely work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if we had a table:

```
create table invoice_partitioned (id int
                                  , department_code INT
                                  , primary key(ID));
```

Then this is the way:

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_partitioned DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE invoice_partitioned ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, department_code);
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=875dc052df8cf1fb1a418efcfd8190c3)

This will also work:

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_partitioned
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, department_code);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29c89153745238521759e791bb64de0d)

Comment: Thank you, this works. What is the reason that removing the table name in the second version removes the error?

Comment: I am not sure why, but I can assume that it is because you are altering that table and can not add primary key column of some other table so it is not allowed I gues... And yes, you are welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in single statement

just don't add table name before column name as shown below

replace

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_partitioned DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(invoice_partitioned.id, invoice_partitioned.department_code);
```

to this

```
ALTER TABLE invoice_partitioned DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, department_code);
```